# CKEDITOR.dom.element.createFromHtml(str); not working in IE

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

***i have tried to create new element and insert after ckeditor's old element***

**Working Code Is Below:**

```
var str = "<Element1>sometext</Element1>";
var Newelement = CKEDITOR.dom.element.createFromHtml(str);
Newelement.insertAfter(oldElement);
```

working in FF & IE

**Non Working Code Is Below:**

```
var str = "<Element1></Element1>";
var Newelement = CKEDITOR.dom.element.createFromHtml(str);
Newelement.insertAfter(oldElement);
```

working in FF
but **not working in IE**

> IE Error:

```
Error on CKEDITOR.dom.element.createFromHtml(str) 

The Error :  'getFirst()' is null or not an object
```

Error Number : -2146823281

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be this can be bug in IE i guess

If you are trying to create element in Head (if your code is between  it was not able to create in  tags) there is a patch for this but i could not find the link

Or try to create element in  (put your script block in same section with the destination)

This can solve your issue

This issue is specific to IE-8
if you try with IE-9 it must not be the case

Comment: that problem is only when we create dummy element(without any text content)

Comment: how do i create dummy element (IE8)

Comment: var element = document.createElement('tagName')